# Android DrawerLayout background selection on ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I've developped an app with a DrawerLayout.

My problem is with the `ListView`, when I click on an item his `textColor` becomes white, but background still transparent and the `ListView` background is white. So selected text is unreadable.

I searched solutions, and tried many of them but no one is working. I just want to change background color in `#FFCCCCCC` for example when an item is selected.

Do you have any idea ?

**Drawer layout**

```
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFDDDDDD"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Navigation list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you have any solution...
Thanks :)

**Edit :**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you post your output

Comment: Done :) You can see the text "Paramètres" which is selected

Comment: try setting android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" for listview

Comment: Not changed anything :/

Comment: try specifying the `TextView`'s text color `android:textColor="@android:color/black"`

Comment: But the text isn't a problem, it becomes white when it's selected and I want it. 
But I want the background becomes dark at the same time, and this is the problem.

Comment: Not yet, and I'm not working on it currently. Be sure that I will update if I found the solution

Answer (score 4):

When defining your selector for the background of a list item, have a section for `android:state_activated="true"` as well. Re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917947/954643 Pretty annoying that a `ListView#setItemChecked()` call doesn't actually set the selected state...but I guess that's why they have a separate `#setSelection`. Wish the docs were clearer about the state it puts items in.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a selector for both `android:background` and `android:textColor`. See [Color State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for further details!

**Navigation list**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/color_selector"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**background_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

**color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Comment: The state "when an item is selected" @Kyu_ is asking about may actually be the "activated" state.

Comment: On DrawerLayout items, "Activated" is after you clicked an item AND released it. It is the state you get calling `mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);` on your Drawer ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The menu item background should point to a selector rather than a simple drawable or color, something along these lines:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_background" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Then do include some code about how you tried with selectors because this *is* the way to do it. I'm right inside an app I'm working on and its drawer does work all right with properly changing backgrounds. Using this approach. :-)

Comment: Hi, i just restarted to work on drawers and your solution is interesting me. I tried to use your code but not worked. So here is my question: On what have you applied this selector ? Items in the adapter ? List ? ... ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, in the MenuAdapter, I call them MenuItems, those are what I inflate in the GetView() of the MenuAdapter.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the "activated" state rather than the "selected" one.
<!-- language: xml -->
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
        <item android:state_activated="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/green"/>
        <item android:color="@color/blue"/>
    </selector>

Answer (score 0):

on your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_SELECTOR);
    rowView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    return rowView;
}
```