# onItemClick listview sets color of 2 items

Tags: android, listview

Following scripts sets the color of (for example) ListItem position 1, but it also gives number 12 (11+1) a nice grey color. Is this some kind of bug in Android?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    ListView.setSelection(arg2);
    arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: You mean, item at 12th position also changing color?

Comment: what do you trying to achieve with this code ?

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` recycles (reuses) the views. So you need to associate the background color with the **data**, not the view! Then, in `getView()` you have the chance to correctly set the background color based on the **data**.

Answer (score 0):

@David Wasser is correct ... cell re-use is causing multiple listview rows to draw with gray background.

However, if you're trying to set your background based on SELECTION STATE, consider this technique:

```
// set single or multi-select on your list (CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE = single row selectable)
// do this in onCreate
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
.
.
.
// in your onItemClick, set the checked state of the item
// you DO NOT need to call notifyDataSetChanged
listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

And, set the background on your listview cell layout to the built-in or a custom selector

BUILT-IN:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

CUSTOM:

```
android:background="@drawable/myListBackground"
```

*drawable/myListBackground.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/lightgray" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

the key is the state_activated entry, which will be used when the item is selected/checked.  You can also specify colors for other states, the above example references colors from a colors.xml table.

For more details on this, please check out [How does "?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008150/how-does-androidattr-activatedbackgroundindicator-work)