# Keeping Custom Selector Color in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

Instead of continuing the search on how to do this I thought I would pose the question here and see if I had any luck. I am working on an Android app that uses a navigation drawer and I want a custom color when the user touches one of the items in the drawer (not the default light blue). I have three XML files, one for shape/color when not pressed, one for when pressed, and a selector. All of these work great and when a touch on an item in the navigation drawer takes place it shows red like I want. But when the navigation drawer is slid out again the selected item once again shows the default color of light blue. Does anyone know how to keep this custom color selection persistent?

Thank you very much. I certainly appreciate any help!

Comment: I just learned that there is a state selected and I tried this thinking that perhaps it would would but no luck....

Comment: I guess this post can be closed. I found the answer here in this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008150/how-does-androidattr-activatedbackgroundindicator-work