# Understanding the difference between theme and style attributes

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm dealing with Android L color definitions to define the rows of a ListView. I have a theme which has:

```
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_blue_dark</item>
```

and in my row I've defined another one:

```
<style name="DefaultRow">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_sand</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
</style>
```

Assuming that colorAccent value will be overriden. but that doesn't if I do in my row:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ...
          style="@style/DefaultRow"/>
```

[image]

But it works if I do:

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              ...
              android:theme="@style/DefaultRow"/>
```

[image]

What's the difference? is `colorAccent` being defined when the theme is applied and not overriden later? How to solve this to have retrocompatibility?

Comment: Read https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I'm still not clear about why is this happening, as far as I understand, styles are applied locally to the view and themes to it's descendants. But why is this changing the behaviour on the view itself where it is being applied?

Comment: The `android:theme` attribute is applied to the view itself as well as its descendants. Internally, it creates a `ContextThemeWrapper` and inflates the view and its descendants against that context.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` doesn't have a `colorAccent` property. It is a theme property.

Comment: Actually, it does, I'm using ?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator as an attribute for the background and checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008150/how-does-androidattr-activatedbackgroundindicator-work this answer I assume that it's using colorAccent in the back

Comment: But it's still a theme property, not style property. This is why it won't work with styles. It's Android 5 and above only feature